# Problem Sending Value to New Action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently trying to define my first new action in Rails 3, despite various problems I think things are almost done now.  However, I as a final hurdle I am struggling to send the correct parameter value to my function...

My function is defined in `items_controller`:

```
def clickcountplusone
    clickeditem = Item.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to clickeditem.externalurl if clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count, clickeditem.click_count + 1)
end
```

`routes.rb` contains:

```
 match '/items/clickcountplusone', :to => 'items#clickcountplusone'
```

and the `view` contains:

```
<%= link_to image_tag( item.picture.to_s + ".gif", send("items_clickcountplusone_path", item.item_name)%>
```

The view page itself loads correctly (the one with the link on it), but when I click on the link I get an error:

```
Couldn't find Item with ID=clickcountplusone
{"id"=>"clickcountplusone",
"format"=>"whatever the name is"}
```

and rather than going to the external page, my browser tries to load:

```
http://localhost:3000/items/clickcountplusone.whatever the name is
```

Can anyone tell me how I should be calling the function so that the ID is the `item_name` and the external URL is visited rather than an incorrect one on my site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this would be a normal route, instead of a RESTful route (this is fine). There are some places you have to change.

First, in your controller's action, you used `params[:id]` which is not set actually.

In this particular case, I would suggest you use `params[:item_name]` instead of `id` because you are really sending the `item_name`.

```
def clickcountplusone
  clickeditem = Item.find_by_item_name(params[:item_name])
  redirect_to clickeditem.externalurl if clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count, clickeditem.click_count + 1)
end
```

`Item.find` could only be used if the parameter is one of `the actual id / :all / :first / :last`.

You are finding by the `item_name`, so you should use `Item.find_by_item_name` instead.

Second, you have to update you route too (or else you would need something like /you_path..?item_name=blahblahblah which is fine too if you don't mind)

```
get 'items/:item_name' => 'items#clickcountplusone', :as => :items_clickcountplusone
```

Third, you view. IMO, most of the time if you are using `send` but not writing library / really back end code, you probably misusing it.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{item.picture.to_s}.gif"), items_clickcountplusone_path(:item_name => item.item_name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have ended up combining your answer and that of Dogbert as some of the item_names contained a / and seemed to make things harder than necessary.  I have added an id column and now identify records using that.  The page now loads correctly with no errors, however, when i click on the link i get directed to `items/id` not the external url which is what I was aiming to do.  Am I using the routes wrongly?  Also currently the count is not increasing when i click on the link...  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any variable in your match statement. Try something like

```
match '/items/clickcountplusone/:id', :to => 'items#clickcountplusone'
```

and

```
<%= link_to image_tag(item.picture.to_s + ".gif", items_clickcountplusone_path(:id => item.item_name))%>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am sure that what you suggested is correct, but it gives me the error `No route matches {:controller=>"items", :action=>"clickcountplusone", :id=>"item_name"}`.  I am sure this is me screwing something else up, but if you had an idea what the problem was it would be greatl appreciated.  I get this error when I just try to load the page, i.e. before I have clicked on the link

Comment: Could you confirm that you properly restarted the rails server?

Comment: I tried restarting which didn't fix it but i think i had an inconsistency somewhere else which was the source of the problemm.  Thanks for your help.